# Generating python code from ArgoUML UML model using Open Source tools?

Tags: python, uml, code-generation, argouml

The open source UML tools can be really tricky. Even though exporting/importing in XMI, there seem to be a lot of incompatibilities between tools.

Thus, I wonder if anybody found a good workflow for generating python code from UML models created in ArgoUML, using Open Source tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try http://argouml-python.tigris.org/ ?  If that doesn't suit, perhaps you could file bug reports so that people could fix the problems.

If you're looking for a different tool, you'll want one which accepts UML 1.4 which is what most recent versions of ArgouML implement.

BTW, the UML/XMI compatibility problem isn't unique to open source UML tools.  It's all rooted in the OMG's complete disregard for compatibility among versions of UML.  Pretty much the only time they maintained compatibility was UML 1.5 which is a pure superset of UML 1.4.  All other versions of UML are completely incompatible -- UML 2.x and UML 1.x hugely so.

Comment: I must admit that the reason I didn't try this one yet was because I didn't find the links to the source code ... so I thought nothing was released yet ... Now that I found the links, I'll try it out!

Comment: Succeeded to build argouml-python now, so clearly this is the answer to my question. Unfortunately it lacks some features I'd wish for, but I'll look into bugging the devs about them, or code them myself .. :)

Comment: I added a post in my blog about how to build it from source here: http://saml.rilspace.org/installing-argouml-python-for-python-code-generation-from-uml

Answer (score 1):

I list some UML-Python tools [here](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#python). Probably PyUML is the best one for your needs

Comment: I tried installing it, but unfortunately couldn't get it working in Eclipse 3.6 ... :/ Otherwise looks promising, as I use Eclipse-based PyDev for my python projects.